# java grpc ignores `maxInboundMessageSize` and fails when payload bigger than 4194304

Tags: java, grpc, netty

Using:

```java
server = ServerBuilder.forPort(port)
    .addService(new MyGRPC())
    .maxInboundMessageSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
    .build()
    .start();
```

with gradle and package versions:

```
def grpcVersion = "1.51.0"

dependencies {
    implementation "io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:${grpcVersion}"
    implementation "io.grpc:grpc-stub:${grpcVersion}"
    ...
}
```

But sending payloads fail with:

```
23/09/19 19:28:25 WARN NettyServerHandler: Stream Error
Error info: Payload length exceeds limit (40000013 > 4194304)
```

Comment: It looks like there are limits to what Netty can support that are below `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.  You may have to figure out a way to use smaller messages, e.g. by streaming smaller messages

Comment: @LouisWasserman tried with smaller values as well, close to 4MB, but even then it fails with the limit `4194304`.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a grpc-java error. It looks to be from Swift. https://github.com/grpc/grpc-swift/blob/84bac657e9930d26e9124bac082f26586dc2d209/Sources/GRPC/GRPCError.swift#L100 That doesn't quite make sense to me. Does it make sense to you? It'd help to have more of the stack trace.